# Represent a character in lexer

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, lexer

I am writing a lexer in OCaml for a small language, I have a part of its grammar as follows:

```
tab-character = %x0009
eom-character = %x0019
space-character = %x0020
underscore = %x005F
single-quote = %x0027 ; '
```

I try to write `let single_quote = [%x0027]` in `lexer.mll`, but I get an illegal character error while compilation,

Could anyone tell me how to specify such numbers as `%x0027`?

The compilation works with the statement `let single_quote = [''']`, I have also seen another way to specify a character, for instance `let black = ['\009']`,

Does anyone know if there is any difference between these 3 ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking about character literals in OCaml.  They are defined in [Section 6.1 of the OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/lex.html#char-literal).

For single quote you can write `'\''` or `'\x27'` or `'\039'`.  All of these are equivalent.  All character literals are written in single quotes--there's no form beginning with a percent (`%`).

Regular expressions in ocamllex can contain character literals (as above), which denote single characters, or string literals (in double quotes), which denote a sequence of characters.  String literals follow the same pattern as character literals.  A string containing just a single quote would be `"'"` or `"\'"` or `"\x27"` or `"\039"`.

I hope this helps.

**Edit**:

Yes, `['\x09']` and `'\x09'` and `"\x09"` are the same when considered as regular expressions.      A set with one thing in it denotes the same thing as that one thing by itself.  Similarly, a sequence of length 1 is the same as just the one thing.

The value 0x3000 in Unicode represents an "Ideographic Space" (used in Chinese, Japanese, and Korean I guess).  Handling Unicode in OCaml is a whole other topic.  There is a Unicode library for OCaml called [Camomile](http://camomile.sourceforge.net/).  I've never used it, but it is well regarded from what I've seen.  I don't think ocamllex works with Unicode.  Just googling quickly I see a lexer generator named [ulex](http://alain.frisch.fr/soft.html#ulex) that handles Unicode.  There are probably others, this is just the top Google hit.

(Whoops, I see Jonathan Protzenko already recommended ulex.  Sorry for extra noise.)

Comment: Thanks... I just would like to make sure that `let a = ['\x09']`, `let a = '\x09'` and `let a = "\x09"` are actually same, right?

Comment: Also, I have seen `DBCS_whitespace = %\x3000`, but `\x3000` (as well as `\x2028`, `\x2029`) does not exist in OCaml, how could I work around that?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to represent non-ascii characters in your lexer, then Ulex is probably what you need. The documentation is at http://cduce.org/ulex/Ulexing.html and the homepage at http://cduce.org/download.html

Comment: [sedlex](https://github.com/ocaml-community/sedlex) is the successor of the ulex project.